# Loader restarts on orientation change

Tags: android

In the Android documentation for Loaders found at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html it says one of the properties of loaders is that:

> They automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to re-query their data.

The following code does not seem to mirror that behaviour, a new Loader is created an finishes querying the ContentResolver, then I rotate the screen and the Loader is re-created!

```
public class ReportFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false);
        return v;
    }

    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Creating loader");
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), ResourcesContract.Reports.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor arg1) {
        Log.d("TEST", "Load finished");
    }

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {

    }

}
```

Here is the output from my logcat:

```
08-17 16:49:54.474: D/TEST(1833): Creating loader
08-17 16:49:55.074: D/TEST(1833): Load finished
*Here I rotate the screen*
08-17 16:50:38.115: D/TEST(1833): Creating loader
08-17 16:50:38.353: D/TEST(1833): Load finished
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I should note that I'm building to Android Google API's version 8, and using the v4 support library.

**2nd EDIT:**

This is most likely due to a bug in the support library, take a look at this bug submission if you want further information:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20791&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

Comment: See this post for more information: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/08/implementing-loaders.html

Comment: Also, you should call `getLoaderManager()` in `onActivityCreated`... your current code will throw an `IllegalStateException` if the `Activity` is still `null` when the `Fragment` is first created.

Comment: @AlexLockwood, in your example (good job!) you are using support-v4:18.0.0. Current version is 23.0.1 and it contains this bug. Latest working version which I tested is 22.0.0.

Comment: I submitted it as bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187391
Latest version of support-v4 who works is 22.2.1.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

onCreate() gets called during screen orientation change since the activity gets destroyed and recreated.

Unless you're loading a lot of data then it doesn't hurt to do, but you can try the following if you want (I haven't tested it, but in theory I think it would work).

Declare a static boolean at the top global of the class. I *think* you'll also need a static cursor to reference

```
private static boolean dataDownloaded = false;
private static Cursor oldCursor;
```

Then on onLoadFinished set dataDownloaded = true

Override onSaveInstanceState to save the boolean value

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outSave) {
    outSave.putBoolen("datadownloaded", dataDownloaded);
    oldCursor = adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

and onCreate add the following

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    this.dataDownloaded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("datadownloaded", false);
}
```

adjust your onCreateLoader

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader cursorLoader;
    if (dataDownloaded) {
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            null, projection, null, null, null);
        cursorLoader.deliverResult(oldCursor);
    } else {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
            URI_PATH, projection, null, null, null);
    }

    return cursorLoader;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this query the ContentResolver either way (doesn't matter if dataDownloaded is true or false, a new CursorLoader is still created)? Anyway, I think this is actually happening because of a bug with the Support Libraries, see this post for more info: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/DbKL6PVyhLI%5B1-25%5D

Comment: I adjusted it..it was supposed to be "null" for the URI path if the data was already downloaded

Comment: Makes sense now. Well, this is a solution as far as I can see so I will mark it as one. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old question, I've been experiencing the same issue as the OP. Using a loader, I need to have it restarting when navigating to a new Activity, and then back. But at the same time, I don't want the loader to restart when I rotate the phone's screen.

What I found is that it is possible to achieve this in onRestart(), if you restart the loader BEFORE calling its super.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        //Initialize the loader.
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        //Restart the loader before calling the super.
        getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);

        super.onRestart();
    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks :) This helped me with my issue :) I'm using AdapterViewFlipper and following your advice for managing my loader the flipper isn't affected by screen rotation any more :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you misunderstood what the documentation says. The documentations says, that **they don't need to re-query their data**, and it is not doing so.

Try to log/insert a breakpoint in your `ContentProvider#query()` method! The query will be called only on Activity startup, and not after orientation change.

But this is not true for the `LoaderCallbacks#onCreateLoader()` method. It will be called after every orientation change, but this not means re-querying, it just calls the method so you can change the CursorLoader if you want.

Comment: Yes. A new instance of CursorLoader is created (a fairly light-weight operation) on each rotation, but not a new Cursor instance (which would require a potentially heavyweight database query). A reference is kept to the cursor, and the new loader 'reconnects' to it.

Answer (score 0):

So far I found that retaining fragment `Fragment.setRetainInstance(true)` prevents recreating loader on orientation change using support library. The loader last results are nicely delivered in `onLoadFinished()`. It works at least when activity manages single fragment and the fragment is added to activity using `FragmentTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

Though this is a bit old question I would like to put my views here.

There is no need for storing additional info in onSaveInstanceState

The framework automatically reconnect to the last loader's cursor when being recreated after a configuration change. Thus, they don't need to re-query their data.

This means in the onCreate function you need to call loaderManager only if the savedInstanceState is null

Ex:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply check to see if the loader already exists onCreate. Then you can either init or restart.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID) == null) {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    } else {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID);
    }
}
```

You normally pass an ID to your loader so you can reference it later via the loader manager.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Nelson, this would restart the loader if there already exists one, which kind of defies it's purpose. Even if you were to switch the two statements (init and restart), it would result in the same behaviour as just calling initLoader in the first place!

Comment: getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID); does exactly the same as the whole "if() {} else {}" statement because restartLoader does exactly the same if the Loader doesn't exist yet.