# Android - How to prevent ViewPager's Loader restarting on configuration change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-configchanges

I have followed [these steps](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) to create a `ViewPager`, but I have the problem that the loader is restarted when the device configuration changes (e.g., device rotation).

Not only does this result in an unnecessary query, but it also results in a resetting the UI by taking the user back to the first item (i.e., away from the item they were viewing before they rotated their device).

I've tried calling `setRetainInstance(true)` on the fragment that is returned by the `getItem()` method of my `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter` class, but it hasn't helped.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009895/loader-restarts-on-orientation-change) but am expecting / hoping there is a better solution??

Comment: do you want to support both landscape and portrait mode?

Comment: Yes, I need to support both orientations.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) (in particular, [this part](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html#starting)), I have found the solution.

Firstly, I had not called...

`getLoaderManager().initLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, null, this);`

...in my activity's `onCreate` method. But I only achieved the correct behaviour if I called...

`getLoaderManager().restartLoader(MY_LOADER_ID, args, this);`

...on only the **first** time the activity is run. This was the only way to stop a new query from being performed.

So, here is the snippet from my activity's `onCreate` method (which I placed right after creating my `ViewPager` and `ScreenSlidePagerAdapter`)...

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_NORMAL, null, this);

boolean isFirstCreate = (savedInstanceState == null);
if (isFirstCreate) {

    /*
     * If this Activity was launched with a search intent, then perform the search
     */
    parseIntent(getIntent()); //calls getLoaderManager().restartLoader()
}
else {

    /*
     * Hide the progress view
     */
    searchProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Works properly for me, and seems like a fairly clean solution - but any other suggestions appreciated.

**Update: 02 August 2015**

Based on my comment, I think this is the right way of doing it:

```
if (getLoaderManager().getLoader(LOADER_ID_NORMAL) == null) {

    /*
     * Loader doesn't exist, so create and start it
     */ 
    Bundle args = ...;
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID_NORMAL, args, this); //calls onCreateLoader()
}
else {

    /*
     * Loader already exists so all we need to do is initialise it
     */
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_NORMAL, null, this); //calls onCreateLoader()
}
```

Comment: There is no point in restarting the `Loader` upon initialization if you only require initializing the `Loader` once.

Comment: @corsair992 Can you clarify what you mean / Does the code in this answer look OK to you or are you saying `getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID_NORMAL, null, this);` only needs calling when `isFirstCreate == false`?

Comment: Please see the second code snippet I have added to my answer. Can someone confirm that this is the right way to do it?

Comment: Just use `initLoader()` without any conditions. If the loader is not initialized, then restarting it is meaningless, and equivalent to just initializing.

Comment: In which part of the above code should I do that? And what (if any) code should I remove? Please can you post some code as an answer to demonstrate - thanks.

Comment: Remove all the `if` `else` and restart loader logic, and just retain the init loader line...